# HTML object "list" is not updating after switching between sites

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, onsen-ui

**What am I trying to achieve:**

- I am creating simple Firebase project with HTML and Javascript where
  the purpose of app is to create lists of data that is shared across
  users with specific “families”.

**Where is the problem:**

- When I log in and my app goes to the “main.html” site everything
  loads fine and I can see actual items being downloaded from firebase
  into HTML object with ID “list”.  Then when I click log out button –
  again everything is fine.
- The problem occurs when I log back in (after the first logout with the button). I get transferred to the site
  “main.html” but the list does not update … I can see in console that
  I successfully downloaded data from Firebase. The only problem is
  that HTML is not updated.

If you could point me somewhere where I could find answers or point the problem out, I would really appreciate it! 
Already tried to search on internet for “HTML list is not updating” and similar searches but could not find anything.

I have also tried switching "let" for "var" on line 25. Didn't notice any diffrence.

**“main.html” and console after FIRST login:**

[image: App 1]
[image: Console 1]

**“main.html” and console after SECOND login** (as you can see in console data is successfully downloaded from Firebase – but HTML isn’t updated):

[image: App 2]
[image: Console 2]

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //MY FIREBASE CONFIG DATA
    };
    //Other vars.
    var currentPage = "register.html";
    let myListener;
    var email, family, password;

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var auth = firebase.auth();
    var db = firebase.database();

    function login(){
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
                // user signed in
                goToPage('main.html'); 

                firebase.database().ref('/users/' + auth.currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                    family = snapshot.val().family;
                    addDataListener();
                });

            }).catch(function(error) {

                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                console.log(errorCode);

                if (errorCode){
                    ons.notification.alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    }

    function logout(){
        goToPage('login.html'); 

        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
            console.log("I just log out");
            }, function(error) {
             console.log("Some error: ", error);
        });    
    }

    function addDataListener(){
        console.log("Listener is set up!");

        myListener = firebase.database().ref('families/' + family).on('value', function(snapshot) {
            if (currentPage !== "main.html") return;
            console.log(snapshot.val());

            var list = document.getElementById('list'); 

            //Empty list
            while (list.hasChildNodes()) {  
                list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
            }

            //Read all items in firebase and add them to the list
            Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach(function(k){
                console.log(k + ' - ' + snapshot.val()[k]);

                var onsItem = document.createElement('ons-list-item');    
                onsItem.innerHTML = snapshot.val()[k]; 
                onsItem.setAttribute('id', k);
                list.appendChild(onsItem);  
            });

        });
    }

    function goToPage(newPage){
        currentPage = newPage;

        var myNavigator = document.getElementById('myNavigator');
        myNavigator.pushPage(newPage);   
    }
    </script>



    </head>

    <body>
    <ons-navigator swipeable id="myNavigator" page="login.html"></ons-navigator>


    <template id="login.html">
    <ons-page id="login">
    <!--Page name-->
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Login page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

    <!--Inputs-->    
    <ons-list>       
        <ons-list-item tappable>
            <div class="center">
            Email: 
                <ons-input id="email_login" type="email" onchange = "email = this.value"></ons-input>
            </div> 
        </ons-list-item>   

        <ons-list-item tappable>
            <div class="center">
            Password: 
                <ons-input id="password_login" type="password" onchange = "password = this.value"></ons-input>
            </div> 
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>

    <!--Buttons -->  
        <p style="text-align: center"> <ons-button modifier="material" id="login" onclick="login();">Login</ons-button> </p>

    </ons-page>
    </template>

    <template id="main.html">
    <ons-page id="main">
    <!-- Page name -->
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Main page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

    <!--List-->
        <ons-list id="list"></ons-list>

    <!--Buttons -->  
        <p style="text-align: center"> <ons-button modifier="material" id="logout" onclick="logout();">Log out</ons-button> </p>

    </ons-page>
    </template>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with the code a bit and did 2 minor changes.

The thing was `addDataListener()` did not run after `myNavigator.pushPage`

Additionally `myNavigator.replacePage` literally added pages/section to the DOM instead of replacing them. That caused `#list` element to render on the old page instead of the new one ( id should be unique ) so I replaced that with `myNavigator.replacePage`

Seems to work now

```js
goToPage('main.html')
          .then(_ => {
            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + auth.currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              family = snapshot.val().family;
              addDataListener();
            });
          })
```

```js
 function goToPage(newPage) {
      currentPage = newPage;

      var myNavigator = document.getElementById('myNavigator');
      return myNavigator.replacePage(newPage);
    }
```

```js
var currentPage = "register.html";
let myListener;
var email, family, password;

const mockFirebase = {
  initializeApp: () => {},
  auth() {
    return {
      currentUser: {
        uid: 1
      },
      signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => Promise.resolve({}),
      signOut: () => Promise.resolve()
    }
  },
  database() {
    return {
      ref(path) {
        let value = {
          family: 'One'
        }
        if (path.includes("families")) {
          value = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
        }

        return {
          once: () => Promise.resolve({
            val: () => value
          }),
          on: (prop, callback) => callback({
            val: () => value
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

window.firebaseConfig = {}
window.firebase = mockFirebase;

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var auth = firebase.auth();
var db = firebase.database();

function login() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {

    goToPage('main.html')
      .then(_ => {
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + auth.currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          family = snapshot.val().family;
          addDataListener();
        });
      })

  }).catch(function(error) {

    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log(errorCode);

    if (errorCode) {
      ons.notification.alert('Error!');
    }
  });
}

function logout() {
  goToPage('login.html');

  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    console.log("I just log out");
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Some error: ", error);
  });
}

function addDataListener() {
  console.log("Listener is set up!");

  myListener = firebase.database().ref('families/' + family).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (currentPage !== "main.html") return;
    console.log(snapshot.val());

    var list = document.getElementById('list');

    while (list.firstChild) {
      list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach(function(k) {
      console.log(k + ' - ' + snapshot.val()[k]);

      var onsItem = document.createElement('ons-list-item');
      onsItem.innerHTML = snapshot.val()[k];
      onsItem.setAttribute('id', k);
      list.appendChild(onsItem);
    });

  });
}

function goToPage(newPage) {
  currentPage = newPage;

  var myNavigator = document.getElementById('myNavigator');
  return myNavigator.replacePage(newPage);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <ons-navigator swipeable id="myNavigator" page="login.html"></ons-navigator>


  <template id="login.html">
    <ons-page id="login">
    <!--Page name-->
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Login page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

    <!--Inputs-->    
    <ons-list>       
        <ons-list-item tappable>
            <div class="center">
            Email: 
                <ons-input id="email_login" type="email" onchange = "email = this.value"></ons-input>
            </div> 
        </ons-list-item>   

        <ons-list-item tappable>
            <div class="center">
            Password: 
                <ons-input id="password_login" type="password" onchange = "password = this.value"></ons-input>
            </div> 
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
        <p style="text-align: center"> <ons-button modifier="material" id="login" onclick="login();">Login</ons-button> </p>
    </ons-page>
    </template>
  <template id="main.html">
    <ons-page id="main">
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Main page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list id="list"></ons-list>
        <p style="text-align: center"> <ons-button modifier="material" id="logout" onclick="logout();">Log out</ons-button> </p>

    </ons-page>
    </template>
</body>

</html>
```